# Design pattern suggestion for storing the client information in map in server application

Tags: c++, design-patterns, telecommunication

My application is server, and my client will give some request for processing.
Client will contact me(server) for multiple times for handling the same request .

```
map<clientId,ClientInformation>
```

Usually, I'll store some information which I received from the client in STL Map for processing the client request next time.

Once client was satisfied in my servings, I will clear the entry in the map for the respective client Id.

This is my sample `ClientInformation` class:

```
class ClientInformation
{
int NotRequiredForNextTime;  // Information Not required for  processing the client request next time
int requiredforNextTime;  // Information required for  processing the client request next time
int requiredforNextTime;  // Information required for  processing the client request next time
int NotRequiredForNextTime;  // Information Not required for  processing the client request next time
int NotRequiredForNextTime;  // Information Not required for  processing the client request next time

UserDefinedClass Class1;
};

Class UserDefinedClass
{
int requiredforNextTime;
int NotRequiredForNextTime;
}
```

In the above class, I require only `requiredforNextTime` to be stored in the map. other information is required only at the time of processing the current request.

`ClientInformation` class can have user-defined class as member(`UserDefinedClass`), and some of the `UserDefinedClass` members are not required for next time.

Is there is any design pattern, which provided optimized solution(Memory Usage) for this problem?

Comment: What's the problem again?

Comment: What exactly do you want to optimize? Memory usage? Processing time? Wnatever else? So, what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, just separate Required- from NotRequired- fields, in separate classes.  You could...

- have the NotRequired- class be held by pointer in the Required class, such that you could simply `delete` it, or
- have the Required- class be held by pointer in the NotRequired- class, such that you could move it out to some distinct container, or
- keep them in separate containers right from the start, or
- write some code to construct a Required class from a ClientInformation class - copying the Required fields (copying is inefficient, but that might require less change to your existing code, if you have any).

  - "serialisation" is one form of this, albeit in which the data's not necessarily kept in an accessible structure during storage, and a distinct deserialisation step is needed to recreate the Required class, or perhaps repopulate just the Required fields of another ClientInformation object

(I'm not aware of any relevant design pattern names, but not everything you do as a programmer needs to be validated by a design pattern name - developing your mental awareness of data modelling options means you can apply "common sense", named or anonymous.)